# Differentiate Enemy Projectile from User's Projectile

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a user who fires a projectile to damage enemies.

Although some enemies have a projectile of their own to damage the player. They both come from the same projectile script.

The problem is that when the user upgrades his projectile (with the in-game currency). Both the user's and the enemies projectile get upgraded. Since it's from the same script, it updates the `DamageOnHit` of the projectile.

Now my question is: am I able to tell my script to only upgrade the user's projectiles, without creating a separate enemy projectile script?

The projectile code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

//[RequireComponent (typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class Projectile : MonoBehaviour {

    [Header ("Speed")]
    public float baseSpeed;
    public float randomSpeed;
    public Vector2 SpeedV2;
    public Vector2 Direction;

    [Header ("Damage")]
    public static int DamageOnHit = 1;

    [Header ("Layers")]
    public LayerMask solid_layer;
    public LayerMask entities_layer;

    [Header ("OnHit FX")]
    public GameObject HitFxPrefab;
    public GameObject DustFxPrefab;

    [Header ("Bounce")]
    public bool BounceOnCollide = false;
    public int bouncesLeft = 0;

    [HideInInspector]
    public Health owner; // owner of the projectile
    private Vector2 Position; // Current position
    private Vector2 movementCounter = Vector2.zero;  // Counter for subpixel movement
    public BoxCollider2D myCollider;
    List<Health> healthsDamaged = new List<Health>(); // List to store healths damaged

    void Awake () {
        if (myCollider == null) {
            myCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D> ();
        }
    }

    void Start () {
        // keeping everything Pixel perfect
        Position = new Vector2 (Mathf.Round(transform.position.x), Mathf.Round(transform.position.y));
        transform.position = Position;
    }

    void Update () {
        SpeedV2 = new Vector2 (transform.right.x, transform.right.y) * (baseSpeed + Random.value * randomSpeed) * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    void LateUpdate () {
        if (SpeedV2.x != 0) {
            MoveH (SpeedV2.x);
        }

        if (SpeedV2.y != 0) {
            MoveV (SpeedV2.y);
        }
    }

    void DestroyMe () {
        if (HitFxPrefab != null) {
            var h = Instantiate (HitFxPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            h.transform.localScale = transform.lossyScale;
            h.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler (new Vector3(0f, 0f, Random.value * 360f));
        }
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }

    void DestroyMeWall () {
        if (HitFxPrefab != null) {
            var h = Instantiate (HitFxPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            h.transform.localScale = transform.lossyScale;
            h.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler (new Vector3(0f, 0f, Random.value * 360f));
        }
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }

    public void BounceHorizontal () {
        bouncesLeft--;
        transform.right = new Vector3 (-transform.right.x, transform.right.y, transform.right.z);
        SpeedV2 *= 0.8f;
    }

    public void BounceVertical () {
        bouncesLeft--;
        transform.right = new Vector3 (transform.right.x, -transform.right.y, transform.right.z);
        SpeedV2 *= 0.8f;
    }

    void OnCollideWith (Collider2D col, bool horizontalCol = true) {
        var component = col.GetComponent<Health> ();
        // If the target the hitbox collided with has a health component and it is not our owner and it is not on the already on the list of healths damaged by the current hitbox
        if (component != null && component != owner && !healthsDamaged.Contains(component)) {
            // Add the health component to the list of damaged healths
            healthsDamaged.Add (component);

            // Apply the damage
            var didDamage = component.TakeDamage (DamageOnHit);
            // Destroy the projectile after applying damage
            if (didDamage) {
                DestroyMe ();
                return;
            }
        }

        // if the projectile hit's a solid object, destroy it
        if (col.gameObject.layer ==  (int)Mathf.Log(solid_layer.value, 2)) {
            DestroyMeWall ();
            return;
        }
    }

    void OnCollideWithEntity(Collider2D col) {
        var component = col.GetComponent<Health> ();
        // If the target the hitbox collided with has a health component and it is not our owner and it is not on the already on the list of healths damaged by the current hitbox
        if (component != null && component != owner && !healthsDamaged.Contains(component)) {
            // Add the health component to the list of damaged healths
            healthsDamaged.Add (component);

            // Apply the damage
            var didDamage = component.TakeDamage (DamageOnHit);
            // Destroy the projectile after applying damage
            if (didDamage) {
                DestroyMe ();
            }
        }
    }


    // Function to move the Actor Horizontally, this only stores the float value of the movement to allow for subpixel movement and calls the MoveHExact function to do the actual movement
    public bool MoveH(float moveH) {
        this.movementCounter.x = this.movementCounter.x + moveH;
        int num = (int)Mathf.Round(this.movementCounter.x);
        if (num != 0)
        {
            this.movementCounter.x = this.movementCounter.x - (float)num;
            return this.MoveHExact(num);
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Function to move the Actor Horizontally, this only stores the float value of the movement to allow for subpixel movement and calls the MoveHExact function to do the actual movement
    public bool MoveV(float moveV) {
        this.movementCounter.y = this.movementCounter.y + moveV;
        int num = (int)Mathf.Round(this.movementCounter.y);
        if (num != 0)
        {
            this.movementCounter.y = this.movementCounter.y - (float)num;
            return this.MoveVExact(num);
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Function to move the Actor Horizontally an exact integer amount
    public bool MoveVExact(int moveV) {
        int num = (int)Mathf.Sign((float)moveV);
        while (moveV != 0) {
            bool solid = CheckColInDir(Vector2.up * (float)num, solid_layer);
            if (solid) {
                if (BounceOnCollide && bouncesLeft > 0) {
                    bouncesLeft--;
                    num = -num;
                    moveV = -moveV;
                    BounceVertical ();
                } else {
                    this.movementCounter.x = 0f;
                    DestroyMeWall ();
                    return true;
                }
            }

            bool entity = CheckColInDir(Vector2.up * (float)num, entities_layer);
            if (entity) {
                var entit = CheckColsInDirAll (Vector2.up * (float)num, entities_layer);
                OnCollideWithEntity (entit [0]);
            }

            moveV -= num;
            transform.position = new Vector2 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y + (float)num);
        }
        return false;
    }


    // Function to move the Actor Horizontally an exact integer amount
    public bool MoveHExact(int moveH) {
        int num = (int)Mathf.Sign((float)moveH);
        while (moveH != 0) {
            bool solid = CheckColInDir(Vector2.right * (float)num, solid_layer);
            if (solid) {
                if (BounceOnCollide && bouncesLeft > 0) {
                    bouncesLeft--;
                    num = -num;
                    moveH = -moveH;
                    BounceHorizontal ();
                } else {
                    this.movementCounter.x = 0f;
                    DestroyMeWall ();
                    return true;
                }
            }

            bool entity = CheckColInDir(Vector2.right * (float)num, entities_layer);
            if (entity) {
                var entit = CheckColsInDirAll (Vector2.right * (float)num, entities_layer);
                OnCollideWithEntity (entit [0]);
            }

            moveH -= num;
            transform.position = new Vector2 (transform.position.x + (float)num, transform.position.y);
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Helper function to check if there is any collision within a given layer in a set direction (only use up, down, left, right)
    public bool CheckColInDir (Vector2 dir, LayerMask layer) {
        Vector2 leftcorner = Vector2.zero;
        Vector2 rightcorner = Vector2.zero;

        if (dir.x > 0) {
            leftcorner = new Vector2 (myCollider.bounds.center.x + myCollider.bounds.extents.x, myCollider.bounds.center.y + myCollider.bounds.extents.y - .1f);
            rightcorner = new Vector2 (myCollider.bounds.center.x + myCollider.bounds.extents.x + .5f, myCollider.bounds.center.y - myCollider.bounds.extents.y + .1f);
        } else if (dir.x < 0) {
            leftcorner = new Vector2 (myCollider.bounds.center.x - myCollider.bounds.extents.x - .5f, myCollider.bounds.center.y + myCollider.bounds.extents.y - .1f);
            rightcorner = new Vector2 (myCollider.bounds.center.x - myCollider.bounds.extents.x, myCollider.bounds.center.y - myCollider.bounds.extents.y + .1f);
        } else if (dir.y > 0) {
            leftcorner = new Vector2 (myCollider.bounds.center.x - myCollider.bounds.extents.x + .1f, myCollider.bounds.center.y + myCollider.bounds.extents.y + .5f);
            rightcorner = new Vector2 (myCollider.bounds.center.x + myCollider.bounds.extents.x - .1f, myCollider.bounds.center.y + myCollider.bounds.extents.y);
        } else if (dir.y < 0) {
            leftcorner = new Vector2 (myCollider.bounds.center.x - myCollider.bounds.extents.x + .1f, myCollider.bounds.center.y - myCollider.bounds.extents.y);
            rightcorner = new Vector2 (myCollider.bounds.center.x + myCollider.bounds.extents.x - .1f, myCollider.bounds.center.y - myCollider.bounds.extents.y - .5f);
        }

        return Physics2D.OverlapArea(leftcorner, rightcorner, layer);
    }


    // The same as CheckColInDir but it returns a Collider2D array of the colliders you're collisioning with
    public Collider2D[] CheckColsInDirAll (Vector2 dir, LayerMask layer) {
        Vector2 leftcorner = Vector2.zero;
        Vector2 rightcorner = Vector2.zero;

        if (dir.x > 0) {
            leftcorner = new Vector2 (myCollider.bounds.center.x + myCollider.bounds.extents.x, myCollider.bounds.center.y + myCollider.bounds.extents.y - .1f);
            rightcorner = new Vector2 (myCollider.bounds.center.x + myCollider.bounds.extents.x + .5f, myCollider.bounds.center.y - myCollider.bounds.extents.y + .1f);
        } else if (dir.x < 0) {
            leftcorner = new Vector2 (myCollider.bounds.center.x - myCollider.bounds.extents.x - .5f, myCollider.bounds.center.y + myCollider.bounds.extents.y - .1f);
            rightcorner = new Vector2 (myCollider.bounds.center.x - myCollider.bounds.extents.x, myCollider.bounds.center.y - myCollider.bounds.extents.y + .1f);
        } else if (dir.y > 0) {
            leftcorner = new Vector2 (myCollider.bounds.center.x - myCollider.bounds.extents.x + .1f, myCollider.bounds.center.y + myCollider.bounds.extents.y + .5f);
            rightcorner = new Vector2 (myCollider.bounds.center.x + myCollider.bounds.extents.x - .1f, myCollider.bounds.center.y + myCollider.bounds.extents.y);
        } else if (dir.y < 0) {
            leftcorner = new Vector2 (myCollider.bounds.center.x - myCollider.bounds.extents.x + .1f, myCollider.bounds.center.y - myCollider.bounds.extents.y);
            rightcorner = new Vector2 (myCollider.bounds.center.x + myCollider.bounds.extents.x - .1f, myCollider.bounds.center.y - myCollider.bounds.extents.y - .5f);
        }

        return Physics2D.OverlapAreaAll(leftcorner, rightcorner, layer);
    }
}
```

UpgradeMenu Code. As you can see I upgrade the DamageOnHit from the projectile script. That's how ALL projectiles get more damage.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UpgradeMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Text accuracyText;

    [SerializeField]
    private Text speedText;

    [SerializeField]
    private Text damageText;

  [SerializeField]
  private Weapon weapon;

  [SerializeField]
  public Projectile projectile;

  [SerializeField]
  private Player player;

  [SerializeField]
  private int upgradeCost = 50;

    void start ()
    {

    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        UpdateValues();
    }

    void UpdateValues ()
    {

    }

    public void UpgradeArmor ()
    {
      Health.maxHealth += 2;

    ScoreManager.Score -= upgradeCost;

      UpdateValues();
    }

    public void UpgradeSouls ()
    {
      EnemySlime.ScoreOnDeath += 1;
      EnemySkeleton.ScoreOnDeath += 1;

    //  ScoreManager.Score -= upgradeCost;
      UpdateValues();
    }

    public void UpgradeDamage ()
    {
      Projectile.DamageOnHit += 1;

    //  ScoreManager.Score -= upgradeCost;

      UpdateValues();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in what you are trying to achieve, you want to avoid static fields. 
You should be able to work with something like :

```
player.projectile = new  Projectile();
player.projectile.DamageOnHit = 5;

enemy.projectile = new  Projectile(); 
enemy.projectile.DamageOnHit = 1;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

@YouneS answer involves using base classes, this is a better solution but it does mean you'll need a total of 3 classes. 1 base class holding the standard projectile logic and 2 other classes for the player and enemy projectile inheriting the projectile base class. If you don't know what inheritance is here is a link for you: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_inheritance

There's also a different way of doing this. You could create an enum called ProjectileType in the projectile class like so:

```
public Enum ProjectileType { PlayerProjectile, EnemyProjectile }
```

And assign this ProjectileType to a projectileType variable whenever you create/instantiate a projectile like so:

```
private projectileType;

public Projectile(ProjectileType projectileType)
{
    this.projectileType = projectileType;
}
```

Now whenever you upgrade a projectile you can check whether the projectile is of player type like so:

```
if(projectileType == ProjectileType.PlayerProjectile)
{
    // Upgrade logic.
}
```

I still think YouneS's answer is smarter but it's totally up to you!

Comment: Thanks for clarifications and alternatives

Comment: No problem! @YouneS

Answer (score 0):

I am not sur if that is the best solution, because it all depend on your game logic, but you could create two classes of projectiles, one for enemies and one for the player. Both classes can inherite from your Projectile class.

```
public class PlayerProjectil : Projectile {...}
public class AIProjectil : Projectile {...}
```

Make Projectile class functions virtual. and override them inside PlayerProjectil and AIProjectil when you need different behaviour.

Comment: The thing is, I tried copying the projectile class and naming it something else. Adapting my script towards that. The problem with this is that the enemy did not shoot. So this is why I rather have everything inside 1 working script.

Comment: One of the problems I face is that "DamageOnHit" has to be a public static int, since I need to be able to access this class with my UpgradeMenu script. And i'm guessing there is no "Public virtual static int" .